# Highlight.js not working with react-markdown

Tags: reactjs, react-markdown, react-syntax-highlighter

I am using `react-syntax-highlighter@15.4.3` for syntax highlighting. Below is the code:

```
import React, { PureComponent } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { Prism as SyntaxHighlighter } from "react-syntax-highlighter";
import { docco } from "react-syntax-highlighter/dist/cjs/styles/hljs";

class CodeBlock extends PureComponent {
  static propTypes = {
    value: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    language: PropTypes.string
  };

  static defaultProps = {
    language: null
  };

  render() {
    const { language, value } = this.props;
    return (
      <SyntaxHighlighter style={docco}>
        {value}
      </SyntaxHighlighter>
    );
  }
}

export default CodeBlock;
```

```
<ReactMarkdown source={this.state.post.description} renderers={{CodeBlock}}/>
```

I expect it to detect the language automatically supplied to it by `react-markdown`, but it is not detecting the language and hence the code is not beautified.

What should I do so it starts detecting the language by itself?

Comment: What language are you passing as prop?

Comment: I am not passing any language as a prop. I want to to automatically detect the language. Is it possible to implement?

Comment: So that the programming language gets automatically recognized?

Comment: @axtck exactly. Thats what I want to implement.

Comment: I'm not sure if `react-syntax-highlighter` supports this, apparently https://highlightjs.org/ does, maybe give that lib a try. What happens if you don't pass any language to the highlighter?

Comment: I have also used highlight.js and removed the language prop, but it is also not working. I have also updated the code.

Answer (score 2):

I have found the below answer in the documentation of `react-markdown`:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactMarkdown from 'react-markdown'
import SyntaxHighlighter from 'react-syntax-highlighter'
import {docco} from 'react-syntax-highlighter/dist/esm/styles/hljs'
import {render} from 'react-dom'
 
export const renderers = {
  code: ({language, value}) => {
    return <SyntaxHighlighter style={docco} language={language} children={value} />
  }
}
```